# onMessageReceived method is not called, when app is not open

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM in my app, and I need to pass some data from Firebase service to Activity. I have implemented the following code, which works fine, when the app is in foreground(open). When the app is killed or in background, onMessageReceived method is not called, and the launcher activity is loaded while click on the push notification. Also, when the app is open, push message is blank. Kindly advise what I have done wrong. FYI, from backend, they are sending data payload, not notification.

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    public FirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    private static final String TAG = com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
    public static String CHAT_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_INTENT = "chatPushNotificationIntent";
    private PreferencesManager preferencesManager;

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("push token >>", s);
        String reliableIdentifier = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();

        FCMPreferencesManager pref = FCMPreferencesManager.getInstance(this);
        if (pref != null) {
            pref.setStringValue(FCMPreferencesManager.FCM_KEY_VALUE, s);
            pref.setStringValue(FCMPreferencesManager.DEVICE_ID, reliableIdentifier);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        try {
            preferencesManager = PreferencesManager.getInstance(this);
            int userId = preferencesManager.getIntValue(PreferencesManager.LOGIN_USER_ID);
            Log.e("onMessage received >>", "inside service");
            Log.e("userId >>", userId + "");
            if (userId > 0) {
                Log.e("remote message >>", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() + "");
                if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                        handleDataMessage(json);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void classApprovedNotification(int jobId, String stage) {
        if (!Utils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_INTENT);
            pushNotification.putExtra("jobId", jobId);
            pushNotification.putExtra("stage", stage);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
        }
    }


    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            Log.e("total json >> ", json.toString());
            JSONObject data = json.optJSONObject("data");
            Log.e("data >> ", data.toString());
            String title = data.optString("title");
            String message = data.optString("message");
            Log.e("title >>", title);
            Log.e("message >>", message);
            localNotification(data, title, message, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void localNotification(JSONObject data, String title, String message, boolean isSendBird) {

        int type = 0, groupId = 0, classId = 0, jobId = 0;
        String stage = "";
        int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        int userId = preferencesManager.getIntValue(PreferencesManager.LOGIN_USER_ID);
        String className = "", fileName = "";
        if (data != null) {

            jobId = data.optInt("job_id");
            stage = data.optString("stage", "");


        }


        Log.e("jobId in service >>", jobId + "");
        Log.e("stage in service >>", stage);
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirebaseMessagingService.this, VendorHomeActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("jobId", jobId);
        intent.putExtra("stage","stage");
        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        requestID,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                );

        String channelId = "";
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fyxt_logo)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       /* NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);*/
        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        try {
            PowerManager.WakeLock screenLock = null;
            if ((getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)) != null) {
                screenLock = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
                        PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "OOTUSER:WAKE");
                screenLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L /*10 minutes*/);
                screenLock.release();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        classApprovedNotification(jobId, stage);
    }


}
```

In my Activity, I have the following code.

```
 private BroadcastReceiver notificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            jobIdFromNotification = intent.getIntExtra("jobId", 0);
            stageFromNotification = intent.getStringExtra("stage");
            Log.e("jobIdFromNotification >>", jobIdFromNotification + "");
            Log.e("stageFromNotification >>", stageFromNotification);
            prefManager.setIntValue(PreferencesManager.JOB_ID_IN_PREF, jobIdFromNotification);
            prefManager.setStringValue(PreferencesManager.JOB_STAGE_IN_PREF, stageFromNotification);
            classApprovedViewUpdate();
        }
    };

    private void classApprovedViewUpdate() {
        if (jobIdFromNotification > 0) {
            fragmentInteractionCallback = (BaseFragment.FragmentInteractionCallback) this;
            Log.e("inside push receiver update ", "sfs");
            if (stageFromNotification.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.STAGE_TICKET_APPROVAL)) {
                sendActionToActivity(ACTION_CREATE_MAINTENANCE_REQUEST, currentTab, true, fragmentInteractionCallback);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Edit:
data payload:

```
{
"data": {
"type": 0,
"job_id": 123,
"stage": "STAGE_TICKET_APPROVAL",
}
```

Comment: Can you also show us the payload you are sending?

Comment: @DerrylThomas, I have add the data payload in question. Kindly check.